# How did "perfidy" come to mean the absence of faithfulness / trust?

Tags: etymology, prefixes

Perfidy is (OED):

> Deceitfulness, untrustworthiness; breach of faith or of a promise; betrayal of trust; treachery.

The roots are `per-` and `fidēs` (faith)

`Per-` carries several senses, but generally relating to the completeness of a thing:

> Forming words with the sense ‘through, in space or time; throughout, all over’

- pervade
- perambulate
- perfect
- permute
- peruse
- pervert

These words reinforce how the prefix is used to mean *"a completeness of'* the thing that is attached.

"Perfidy", however, does **not** mean 'complete faithfulness and trustworthiness'.

Why not?

Comment: You may want to check this [etymology dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=perfidy)

Comment: It's the sense of Latin prefix ***per*** listed in the full OED as *Forming words with the sense **‘away entirely, to destruction, to the bad’:** with verbs and derivatives, as classical Latin perdere to do away with, destroy, lose (see perdition n.), perīre to go to destruction, perish v., pervertere to turn away evilly, pervert v., perimere to **take away entirely, destroy, annihilate** (see peremptory adj.), etc.*

Comment: This range of meaning had already formed in Latin before French and English took the words over:  **.6. per** by means of, *permission,* ordered ‘through’ someone, **.7. per** under the guise of, under pretence of, with false authority, which accounts for: *perfidy; perjury.*

Comment: I can see now there are documented cases, but is it much to ask yet for understand on how some usages of `per-` came to mean the opposite of 'positive completeness'?

Comment: Just check out Jacinto's link on its etymology, which more less places it on a par with the legal term "in bad faith".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ernest Weekley, *An Etymological Dictionary of Modern English* (1921) has this entry for *perfidy*:

> **perfidy.** F. *perfidie*, L. *perfidia*, from *perfidus*, treacherous, from *fidus*, faithful, from *fides*, faith. For pejorative sense of *per*- cf. *perjure*.

Unfortunately, the entry for *perjure*—after noting a similar origin from French (*perjurer*) and Latin (*perjurare*) and observing that *perjury* is older in English than *perjure*—says only "For pejorative force of *per*- cf. *perfidy*.

But Glynnis Chantreall, *The Oxford Dictionary of Word Histories* (2002) takes the next step and indicates that the prefix per- could mean in Latin (and subsequently in French and English) "to ill effect." Here are Chantrell's entries for *perfidy* and *perjury*:

> **perfidy** {late 16th century} This literary word for 'deceitfulness' came via French from Latin *perfidia* 'treachery', from *perfidus* 'treacherous', based on *per*- 'to ill effect' and *fides* 'faith'. The adjective *perfidious* (from Latin *perfidiosus*) dates from the same period.
>
> ...
>
> **perjury** {late Middle English} *Perjury* is from Anglo-Norman French *perjurie*, from Latin *perjurium* 'false oath', from the verb *perjurare*, literarally 'to swear to ill effect'. This Latin verb also gave rise to late Middle English **perjure** originally used in the form *perjured* meaning 'guilty of perjury'.

So it appears that the prefix *per*- in Latin somehow acquired the sense of "to ill effect" in some of its compounds, and that this sense persisted through the transition to French and on into English—at least in the two words *perfidy* and *perjury*.